# How to handle multiple (not rectangular) selected cells in Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've a Google spreadsheet and bound to it a script to handle selected cells (called from menu).

When I call the method *getActiveRange* I get only the last range of selection but not all (with ctrl) selected cells.

For example I select cell A1, hit the ctrl-button and select C3 and release the button. A1 and C3 is selected but the active Range is only C3.

Is it possible to handle all selected cells?

In the example A1 and C3 should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible at the moment. You can star the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4069).
Let's hope this feature is implemented really soon.